# Sublime Text 2 - backward search

Tags: texlive, evince

I am using Evince 3.6.0 with latexmk and texlive. LaTeXTools states that it should work right of the box with my Setup.

The backward search of Evince (ctrl+click) is not working for me although the forward search works like a charm.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Launch Sublime Text from a terminal, and then see the output/error message in the terminal when you ctrl+click. In my case, the problem was that I was using a symbolic link named sublime while the script expected a binary named sublime-text. Once  I changed my symbolic link to